# How could I reset a command cooldown from an error function

Tags: discord.py

I have a question. It seems that I have no idea how to reset a command cooldown, not in the actual command itself.

````py
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1,900,type=commands.BucketType.member)
async def rob(ctx, left: discord.Member):
  guild=ctx.author.guild
  server_members=guild.members 
  if left in server_members:
    print('found user')
    random_chance = random.randint(0,1)
    if random_chance == 1:
      print('robbery successful')
    else:
      await ctx.channel.send('Robbery not successful lol noob')
  else:
    await ctx.channel.send('That person is not in this server... :sob:')

@rob.error
async def roberror(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
    await ctx.channel.send('You have to supply me with someone to rob.. noob')
  elif isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
    await ctx.channel.send('You have to provide me with a valid person..')
  elif isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
    await ctx.channel.send(f'Chill. Your on cooldown. Try again in {math.ceil(error.retry_after)} seconds')
  else:
    raise error``` I would like to have it reset the command cooldown in the roberror function. Can anyone help me with this?
````

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A command's cooldown can be reset with the `reset_cooldown` attribute, then pass the command context as a parameter. Heres a example using it,

`rob` is the command identifier then `reset_cooldown` is the attribute. This example would reset the cooldown of the command

```
rob.reset_cooldown(ctx)
```

It seems you would like to put this when the "rob" command was unsuccessful, you can just add it like this:

```
else:
    await ctx.channel.send('Robbery not successful lol noob')
    rob.reset_cooldown(ctx)
```

You can find more information in the documentation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html

Comment: Actually, no I think you must of read the question wrong. What I need to do is reset the cooldown in the actual error handler, not in the command itself.

Comment: You can put it in there too @BeginnerPythonLearner It was meant to be an example

Comment: Would you mind marking the answer if it helped?